# XML Serialization issue - duplicate XmlRoot node

Tags: c#, xml

I am working with a third party XML API, that returns XML responses. With the API, I am trying to import orders. So, two scenario could occur when I import order with this API:

- Success - e.g. xml response: http://pastebin.com/ZcvvYMX6
- Failure - e.g. xml response: http://pastebin.com/iVjqMKAR

What I am working on is a wrapper for this API and I have a method called `ImportOrders`. Within this method, I am trying to deserialize the xml to an object so that I can return a common response.

For example; I will have a common response DTO class like this:

```
public class ImportOrderResponse
{
    bool IsError { get; set; }
    string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
}
```

and the `ImportOrders` method will return response conditionally like this:

```
if (apiResult.Contains("importFailures"))
{
    // todo: deserialize
    return new ImportOrderResponse()
    {
        IsError = true,
        ErrorMsg = "todo - get failureMessage"
    };
}
else
{
    // todo: deserialize
    return new ImportOrderResponse()
    {
        IsError = false,
        Result = "todo - haven't worked out what i need to return"
    };
}
```

Using this site http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net I've generated the classes used for deserialization like this:

**ImportSuccess.cs**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "import")]
public class ImportSuccess
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "operation")]
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "entity")]
    public string Entity { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "externalReference")]
    public string ExternalReference { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "queryTime")]
    public string QueryTime { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importSuccesses")]
public class ImportSuccesses
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "import")]
    public List<ImportSuccess> Import { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importResult")]
public class ImportResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importSuccesses")]
    public ImportSuccesses ImportSuccesses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importFailures")]
    public string ImportFailures { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importDuplicates")]
    public string ImportDuplicates { get; set; }
}
```

**ImportFailure.cs**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "import")]
public class ImportFailure
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "failureMessage")]
    public string FailureMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "failureDetail")]
    public string FailureDetail { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "operation")]
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "externalReference")]
    public string ExternalReference { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "queryTime")]
    public string QueryTime { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importFailures")]
public class ImportFailures
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "import")]
    public ImportFailure Import { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importResult")]
public class ImportResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importSuccesses")]
    public string ImportSuccesses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importFailures")]
    public ImportFailures ImportFailures { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importDuplicates")]
    public string ImportDuplicates { get; set; }
}
```

But now I have a problem. Both the success & failure response contains the node `importResult` but has varying fields/element names.

Now I have an error because I have a duplicate `ImportResult` class.

How can I solve this? What is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you not change the name of the second ImportResult class? or add the class to a different namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was being silly... I was going about this with a wrong approach.

What I did was;

- Call api with correct data for a success response, took the xml and created a class
- call api with wrong/bad data for a failure response, took the xml and tried to create another class

After some digging around, I realised that the response structure is very close for success/failure.

So, I called the api and instead of sending one order; I sent 3 orders for 3 specific scenario. This resulted in a single XML response like this:

http://pastebin.com/sNgWAwq1

Now I have a good structure of the XML for (Success/Failure & Duplicates). Using this XML, I've generated the following class (for deserialisation purpose):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "import")]
public class Import
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "operation")]
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "entity")]
    public string Entity { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "externalReference")]
    public string ExternalReference { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "queryTime")]
    public string QueryTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "failureMessage")]
    public string FailureMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "failureDetail")]
    public string FailureDetail { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "duplicateMessage")]
    public string DuplicateMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "duplicateDetail")]
    public string DuplicateDetail { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importSuccesses")]
public class ImportSuccesses
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "import")]
    public List<Import> Import { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importFailures")]
public class ImportFailures
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "import")]
    public Import Import { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importDuplicates")]
public class ImportDuplicates
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "import")]
    public Import Import { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "importResult")]
public class OrderImportResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importSuccesses")]
    public ImportSuccesses ImportSuccesses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importFailures")]
    public ImportFailures ImportFailures { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "importDuplicates")]
    public ImportDuplicates ImportDuplicates { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this can work for me. I can call the api and deserialise the response to the `OrderImportResponse` class (without checking what kind of xml response it was) and it will have all three scenario responses I am looking for.